# Can we ensure that whenever there is an update to an item on master list, the same item should be updated

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Is there a way in SharePoint designer 2013,  I can ensure that whenever there is an update to an item on master list, the same item should be updated in the copy list of the master list in other site collection. I have a master list in one site collection and copy of it’s in other site collection?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, no.  But there are some 3rd party tools, and coding options discussed on a SharePoint StackExchange posting:  https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/139417/workflow-create-list-item-to-another-site.